# Holding a Shepherd's pie until dinner

Tags: cooking-time

I made a Shepherds pie for dinner, its assembled and ready to bake.  I'd like to hold off for a few hours though, maybe 4-5 hours.

I have no room in my fridge and I don't want to leave it on the counter, so I think the oven is my only option.  The instructions say to bake it at 450 for 30 minutes.  Should I bake it as instructed, then hold it at 200 until ready to eat?    Are there any other methods to do this?

Thanks

Comment: The whole point of a shepherds pie was that it could wait in the oven until the shepherd finally dragged in from the field. The potatoes might dry a bit, but a crispy top is a feature :-)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, keeping it in a 200F oven will keep it safely outside the bacterial danger zone, but it may also dry out a bit. Covering with foil or adding a pan of water to the rack below may help that, though that may also make the crust soggy. You'll have to experiment a bit.

Comment: If you bake it and hold it wrapped, you can then take the foil off and put it under the broiler to brown the top just before serving